# Open email window to allow physical input

Tags: python, outlook

I want the user to be able to manually complete an email in an actual instance of Outlook as opposed to hard-coding the values or input in the shell.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = '***'
mail.Subject = '***'
mail.Body = '***'
mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call `mail.Send()` - call `mail.Display(true)` to display the message modally.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` built-in. Example:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = input("Mail to: ")
mail.Subject = input("Mail Subject: ")
mail.Body = input("Mail Body: ")
attachment = str(output_file)
attachpath = "my_attachment_path"
attachfull = attachpath+attachment
attachf = str(attachfull)
mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachf)
mail.Send()
```

Comment: Wonderful - is there any way to make it pop up in a box vs the shell without having to create something complex?
My listbox with tkinter took me much longer than it should have haha.

Comment: tkinter is really your best way to go. There are some hacky ways to do it but you're better off just learning tkinter for the simple stuff like this. It gets easier

Comment: thanks - last question if i may, then i'll mark it as answered. is there a way to open the physical mail message with the attachment attached and then just let the user do the rest manually?

Comment: I didn't go too deep down the outlook.application rabbit hole, but I would be willing to be that it is definitely doable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application

example
`Sub CreateAnotherNewDefaultOutlookTask() 
    Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem 
 
    ' You can only use CreateItem for default items 
    Set NewTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem) 
    ' Display the new task form so the user can fill it out 
    NewTask.Display 
End Sub`

Comment: turns out if we just change mail.send() to mail.Display(True) it adds the attachment and then opens the email to be finished!